# Can I generate validation rules by @ORM annotations?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

consider this doctrine entity

```
class Product 
{
     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=24, nullable=false)
      */
     private $title;
}
```

Can I somehow generate @Asserts annotations by @ORM annotations.
So after this generation I would have this class.

```
class Product 
{
     /**
      * @Assert\NotBlank()
      * @Assert\Length(max="24")
      *
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=24, nullable=false)
      */
     private $title;
}
```

Comment: @Assert\Length(max="24") you mean?

Comment: yes, you're right. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it automatically. But possible to create custom generator for it.

Alternatively, you can create [custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) which validate entity based on ORM mapping;

Comment: That's a pity. This would be a great feature wouldn't it ?

Comment: Yes, I think it's great idea.